# signal stability lora vs bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, iot, lora

I've tested bluetooth and lora module sx127x. 
Am I correct that sx127x 433Mhz or Lora modules give better RSSI signal strength  in buildings at all? 
On BT I get's big difference about 20 - 40 between two reads in one/two seconds (ex. -70 and -92). 
On lora after first tests I get 2-3 (ex. -112 and - 114).

Comment: It depends on your overall setup. LORA is built to overcome long ranges by using spread spectrum at the cost of tranmission speed.

Answer (score 0):

LoRa will blow Bluetooth out of the water. I put together a modem using an off-the-shelve LoRa transceiver, at approximately 905MHz, transmitting at about 200mW and the thing was communicating 10 miles to the base station on a tower (line of sight).

LoRa has very low data throughput, it would never work to transmit music for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison in terms of RSSI is not very accurate because RSSI is a normalized value that varies from technology and even manufacturer, LoRa is a pure signal transmission method and Bluetooth implement a communication protocol, you should be comparing LoRaWAN to Bluetooth.

if your concern regarding RSSI is due to communication range you should notice that LoRaWAN is a sub 1ghz technology that aims to be low power and Long range communication, the price is the data transference capability. and Bluetooth is 2.4Ghz technology. Bluetooth signal is digitalized via FSK and LoRa is CHIRP which makes them different by nature also.

If you are searching for a single network gateway capable of supply an entire building a LoRa gateway would be more appropriate because it can reach several kilometers range.

Hope it helped let me know in any case.

Answer (score -1):

Lora will be a lot more stable than bluetooth, because its operating at a frequency where you have next to none other disturbing devices. Bluetooth works on 2.4Ghz, which is the same frequency as WLAN. I think it depends on what you want to transmit.

Due to the lower frequency of LoRa it will better penetrate buildings. But be aware, LoRa is available in many frequencies, but only some of them will be allowed in your area. If you use a restricted frequency you can get into some big troubles.